# How to shorten conditional #available in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code that should only be run on iOS versions below iOS 10.

Currently, the code is as follows:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // Ignore
} else {
    // Some code to run for < iOS 10
}
```

What I am looking to do is shorten this to something like this:

```
if !(#available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
    // Some code to run for < iOS 10
}
```

But this fails with the message:

> #available may only be used as condition of an 'if', 'guard' or 'while' statement

How can I shorten statements like this without needing an empty if brace?